# Get a list of net service names in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle-10g

I'm trying to connect to a Oracle 10g database using the "Oracle Administration Assistant", however there's a field there called "Net Service Name".

I'm not sure what to put in there, I only have the DB name, the user and its pw, but no "net service name".

Is there a way to get a list of the net service names available for Oracle?

I ran "net start" and I could see a list of services, one of them called OracleServiceMyAppsName, but when I submit it in, I get this error:

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle's [glossary](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/glossary.htm#BGBHHCEE) mentions

> A simple name for a service that resolves to a connect descriptor. Users initiate a connect request by passing a user name and password along with a net service name in a connect string for the service to which they want to connect:
>
> ```
> CONNECT username@net_service_name
> ```
>
> Depending on your needs, net service names can be stored in a variety of places, including:
>
> - Local configuration file, tnsnames.ora, on each client
> - Directory server
> - External naming service, such as NIS or CDS

---

> I ran "net start" and I could see a list of services, one of them called OracleServiceMyAppsName

Right, that corresponds to the SID/Service, not necesrily the connect descriptor. I'd recommend you have a look at the TNS entry for `OracleServiceMyAppsName` in `%ORACLE_HOME%\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora` and enter that TNS name in the dialog box